# R install.packages returns error failed to create lock directory

Tags: r

When I try to install packages in R I keep receiving this error. I already followed the instructions and deleted 00LOCK but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

package ‘highr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘\Mac\Home\Documents\R\win-library\4.1’ for modifying
Try removing ‘\Mac\Home\Documents\R\win-library\4.1/00LOCK’

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend you do what the error message says and remove the file `\Mac\Home\Documents\R\win-library\4.1/00LOCK`.

Comment: If the removal of `00LOCK` doesn't solve it, you could try setting `options(install.lock = FALSE)` before your install, or use `install.packages("highr", INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')`. This worked for me (on windows).

Comment: Those are weird paths:  sort of like Windows, but not really.  What system are you working on?